# Implement a simple mathematical function - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm extremely new at coding, I'm supposed to write the function `g(t)` and get the result of `g(0)` and `g(1)`. 
 I wrote code hoping to achieve that goal but I'm getting the error:

> File "[user code]", line 7, in g TypeError: 'float' object is not callable" 
>   and I have no clue how to fix it.

Question:

```
g(t)=exp(−t)sin(πt),
```

in a Python function g(t). Print out g(0) and g(1).

Code I wrote:

```
import math     
from math import exp         
from math import sin
from math import pi   
def g(t):    
    g=exp(-t)*sin(pi*t)   
    return (g(0,1))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry I'm extremely new at coding, I'm supposed to write the function g(t) and get the result of g(0) and g(1), I wrote that code hoping to achieve that goal but I'm getting the error "File "[user code]", line 7, in g
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable" and I have no clue how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ehm

```
import math     
from math import exp         
from math import sin
from math import pi   

def g(t):    
    return exp(-t)*sin(pi*t)
```

Or are you trying to implement a recursion?

then you need to define a base condition too, otherwise it will go infinitely.

EDIT:
If you want g(0) and g(1) you simply do

```
g0 = g(0)
g1 = g(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want g(0) and g(1) then you should redfine the function g:

```
def g(t):    
    return exp(-t)*sin(pi*t)
```

Then call `g(0)` and `g(1)`:

```
print(g(0))
print(g(1))
```